# asp.net gridview without database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

Hi guys I have a question. Is there some way to populate a gridview in asp.net without using a database? I'm using a gridview to show information but I've seen that everytime I try to insert more rows to the grid the last row is changed with a new one and overwrites the data

I'm using the following code:

> ```
> Dim dtsetinform As New DataSet
> Dim datatableinfo As New DataTable("fill")
>
>    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>
>    dtsetinform.Tables.Add(datatableinfo ) 
>    gridfactura.DataSource = datatableinfo 
>    datatableinfo.Columns.Add("Name") '
>    datatableinfo.Columns.Add("Quantity")
>    datatableinfo.Columns.Add("Price")
>
>    Session("fill") = datatableinfo 
>
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub agregarfilas(ByVal total As Integer)
>
>    datatableinfo = Session("fill")
>
>    Dim row As DataRow = datatableinfo .NewRow
>    row("Name") = ddserviciotxt.Text 
>    row("Quantity") = cantidadtxt.Text
>    row("Price") = total
>    datatableinfo .Rows.Add(row)
>
>    ViewState("tablainViewState") = datatableinfo 
>    datatableinfo .AcceptChanges()
>    gridfactura.DataSource = datatableinfo 
>
>    gridfactura.DataBind()
>
> End Sub
>
> Protected Sub btnagregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnagregar.Click
> Dim result As Integer
> Dim price As Integer = preciotxt.Text
>
> Dim quantity As Integer = cantidadtxt.Text
>
> result = price * quantity 
> agregarfilas(result)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the code in the page load in

```
if not Page.IsPostBack then
your code
end if
```

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much ! Now the grid shows the data just like I wanted. Thanks !